# Copper pipe drain hole attachment to blow out water line?

Tags: plumbing, compressor, winterizing, copper-tubing, air-compressor

Trying to winterize better.  Copper pipe feeds normal garden water hose.    How would one attach an air compressor Attachment to thread on here to blow out water line? to this to blow out?  If you have better terminology for the parts pictured, that would help.

Coarse thread “1/8inch”

[image: Picture of copper pipe with small drain cap.]
[image: Drain cap blowing bubbles]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

Comment: Usually just need to add a blow out valve on it, most hardware/plumbing stores should have it.

Comment: That's intended as a drain. Whether you can find any fittings to fit it other than the cap that comes on it is a bit of a gamble. It could be a standard thread - or not.

Comment: @crip659, you mean attach to outside of house like this adapter.   Air Compressor Quick-Connect Plug To Female Garden Faucet Blow Out Adapter.    Back

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Winterize-Sprinkler-Systems-Outdoor-Faucets/dp/B017CKUKHS/ref=pd_aw_di_ci_mcx_2l_mi_ca_mcx_picks_views_0?pd_rd_w=rJ1K3&pf_rd_p=3fe70698-0cfc-4664-ada9-f60598343b42&pf_rd_r=R14FN5HE6WVECK63WS8V&pd_rd_r=695c0c27-034d-43ac-b3c8-c809c9e480e5&pd_rd_wg=AmxKg&pd_rd_i=B017CKUKHS#

Comment: @rjt   Was thinking more of a tee/cap fitting with an air valve(tire valve), but Ecnerwal mention that might be a shutoff drain valve/fitting.

Comment: that does just look like a drain.  Why do you want to winterize better?  shutoff water at this valve, open outside to allow air in and open that drain cap and presumably any water in the line will drain out (assuming it is gravity plumbed properly)

Comment: @Fresh-CodeMonger ,  that is what I have been doing.   Winters in Nebraska often long stretches of summer days.   Subsequently, we have to flush some garden hoses a few times per year.   Trying to find a much quicker way.   If I can find a way to blow out from here in the basement, it also blow out the garden hose at same time.   More importantly, the water drains outside instead of holding a bucket in basement.

Comment: @ecnerwal,  yes it is 1/8inch course thread.   Why they call it 1/8”, I have no idea.   Diameter is more like 1/4” or 3/8”.   Could find nothing at Menards that fit it.

Comment: Pipe threads are nominal for the hole inside the pipe, so the threads are always bigger than the "size"

Answer (score 1):

Use a rubber tipped blow gun. You should be able to hold it in place, doesn't seem like something you need a threaded connection for.
[image: Blow gun]

Comment: I lost track of this question until now.  I never thought of trying a rubber tipped blow gun partly because non of mine are rubber tipped.   Did not find try anything special this year, at least not yet.